# Absolute import not finding the module. / React

Tags: reactjs, import, absolute

I have an component which I want to import 'homeSlice'

Home slice (which is located in the 'pages' folder) :

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


const initialState = [
{ id: 1, name: "Andy" },
{ id: 2, name: "Nathan" },
{ id: 3, name: "Andrei" },
];

const homeSlice = createSlice({
name: "users",
 initialState,
reducers: {},
});

export const selectHomeUsers = (state) => state.home;

export const homeReducer = homeSlice.reducer;
```

And then I have another component in which I make the next import :

```
import {homeReducer} from 'pages';
```

And I have the next jsconfig.json file :

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "*": ["src/*"]
}
}
}
```

But when I try to run the app, I get the error that there is no module found **'pages'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Where is the "pages" file located?
2. You didn't export `homeSlice`
3. When importing a non-default, you must wrap the imported items in curly braces, like so :

   `import { homeSlice } from 'pages'`

Edit: I realized now that "pages" is a folder and not a file. You have to import the file where your variables are located, not the folder. If you wish to import from a folder you have to create an "index.js" file. See [this article](https://dev.to/fahadaminshovon/-how-to-use-indexjs-fileproperly-302f) for more info

Comment: Pages is where the homeSlice is located. And I dont need the homeSlice variable, I need its reducers, I just named it homeSlice.

Comment: By "located" I meant where in the folder heirarchy the "pages" file is located.

Comment: Its located in the main 'src' file where are the the files of my project are located. As well as where I import that homeReducer

Comment: And if you want to import without curly braces, you must add a `default` keyword after the `export` keyword for the variable that you want to import

Comment: Does it work if you do a relative import?

Comment: Yes it does work if I do a relative import, I just wanted to implement an absolute one in my project

Comment: Wait, I just reread your question - is "pages" a folder and not a file? You have to import the file where exports are located, not the folder. If you want to import from a folder you have to create an "index.js" file in said folder, then reimport the variables into the index.js file and then export them from the index.js file

Comment: @MetgherAndrei glad I could help :) would be nice if you accepted my answer.